# Yolov8 detect overlap object from detected models

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, yolov8

```py
def get_person_in_possession(
    gym_equipment_detections: List[Detection], 
    person_detections: List[Detection],
    proximity: int
) -> Optional[Detection]:
    if len(person_detections) != 1:
        return None
    person_detection = person_detections[0]
    for gym_equipment_detection in gym_equipment_detections:
        if gym_equipment_detection.rect.pad(proximity).contains_point(point=person_detection.rect.center):
            return gym_equipment_detection #return List
```

I want to detect every person in possession of equipment (detected objects) using `get_person_in_possession` function. The current code works fine for a single person, but I want it to work for multiple persons. Here is the snippet code btw I am using yolo8 and supervision.